# Keep first line and delete everything up to a pattern for all paragraphs

Tags: awk, logs

I have a log file that contains data like this.

```
criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile_1
    someting something useless data
    something something useless data
    more useless data
        Old run: exit speed=22.5
        Old run: ramp speed=15.2
        New run: exit speed=28.2
        New run: ramp speed=19.3

criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile 3
    someting something useless data
    something something useless data
    more useless data
        Old run: exit speed=25.3
        Old run: ramp speed=18.6
        New run: exit speed=29.5
        New run: ramp speed=17.9
```

This is my desired output:

```
criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile_1
        Old run: exit speed=22.5
        Old run: ramp speed=15.2
        New run: exit speed=28.2
        New run: ramp speed=19.3

criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile 3
        Old run: exit speed=25.3
        Old run: ramp speed=18.6
        New run: exit speed=29.5
        New run: ramp speed=17.9
```

I've used `awk 'NR==1||c-->0;/^$/{c=1}' logs.txt` to get the first line of every paragraph 
and I have used `sed 's/^.*\(Ref\)/\1/' logs.txt` to delete everything before the word Ref, but all that does is removes the tabs. I'm not sure how to combine everything to get my desired output.

Comment: There is no `Ref` in your posted sample input/output so we can't tell why you were trying to do something with that. To get the first line of each paragraph with awk is just `awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '{print $1}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something stateful like

```
/first-pattern/ {print; p = 0} /second-pattern/ {p = 1} p
```

Ex.

```
$ awk '/^criteria/ {print; p = 0} /(Old|New) run:/ {p = 1} p' file.log
criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile_1
        Old run: exit speed=22.5
        Old run: ramp speed=15.2
        New run: exit speed=28.2
        New run: ramp speed=19.3

criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile 3
        Old run: exit speed=25.3
        Old run: ramp speed=18.6
        New run: exit speed=29.5
        New run: ramp speed=17.9
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. If possible, can you write out a breakdown of the command. Just trying to understand it so that I can troubleshoot it or modify it by myself later on if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Given your posted sample input/output all you need is:

```
$ grep -v '^    [^ ]' file
criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile_1
        Old run: exit speed=22.5
        Old run: ramp speed=15.2
        New run: exit speed=28.2
        New run: ramp speed=19.3

criteria (NO-NO) data/speed/profile 3
        Old run: exit speed=25.3
        Old run: ramp speed=18.6
        New run: exit speed=29.5
        New run: ramp speed=17.9
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu sed with the range operator is a fit for this scenario:

```
$ sed -Ee '
    /^criteria/,/^$/!d
    //b
    /(Old|New) run:/!d
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep '(criteria|run:)' file
```

should work fine as long as neither of these two patterns occur in the "something something useless data" part.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command

```
awk '/criteria/||/:/{print $0}' filename
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you explicitly said that this would print lines that contain the word "criteria" or a colon, in case their "useless data" contains colons (which isn't yet specified).